# Codeigniter Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, fatal-error

Now I am learning Codeigniter. I have more databases, so I choosed this time Anketa one.
Why is error :

```
**Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/domains/svastara/application/controllers/anketa.php on line 12** ???
```

I chacked, the user and pass in database is ok, database is loaded in conf, and chacked the table name. So what more?

```
$this->db = $this->load->database('anketa');

        $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM anketaip");

        if($q->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        }return $data;

        $this->load->view('anketa_nova', $data);
```

Comment: what you get in var_dump($this->db) ?

Comment: paste that result in your question

Comment: if I put it right in the code, the answer is (I echo it before query row):
bool(false)

Comment: I SOLWED IT :) THANKS GUYS FOR HELP!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below line doesn't return you database object until you pass second argument as TRUE

Change:

```
$this->db = $this->load->database('anketa');
```

To

```
$newdb = $this->load->database('anketa',TRUE);

$q = $newdb->query("SELECT * FROM anketaip");
```

Reference Link: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Comment: If I do that i have an Error: 

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Comment: I read somewhere if there is more databases with same user and pass its better to put FALSE if I want them to work.

Comment: can you paste your database.php data ?

Comment: I SOLWED IT :) THANKS GUYS FOR HELP!:)

Comment: First time that what you wrote here, after, i copied one pass in DB conf, And I forgot to change the database group name.

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to do this

```
$this->db = $this->load->database('anketa');
```

You can simply do it like this

```
$this->load->database('anketa');

$this->db->query('blah blah');
```

Also make sure database exists and you have rights to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Posibly you need to load the DB library, please check in you autoload.php that you are loading the database library

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Or load the library in your controller

```
$this->load->library('database');
```

Comment: I SOLWED IT :) THANKS GUYS FOR HELP!:)

Comment: Please, say what is the problem

Comment: First time that what GBD wrote, after, i copied one pass in DB conf, And I forgot to change the database group name.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Daniela,

I think this resource link may help u. Because when you are using more than one database at a time u need to follow the syntax explained by GDB in his post. But you said unable to access to database that means it's not able to detect database,php in config folder. So put that file link externally in your php file. Then it may work.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/191673/

Comment: I SOLWED IT :) THANKS GUYS FOR HELP!:)

Comment: how u solved daniela.......whats the error if my post helped you accept it as answer..

Answer (score 0):

That was the problem.
I set `$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE`
and it worked.